# Python - выборочное сравнение значений внутри списка

Tags: python, список, сравнение

> Есть некий список [а]. Нужно чтобы в нем шла пошаговая проверка на
> a[i]>a[i-1].  При срабатывании условия значение a[i] добавляется в
> список d.  Последующие выполнения условия a[i]>a[i-1] игнорируются
> (важно!). При срабатывании условия a[i]< a[i-1] значение a[i]
> добавляется в список d. Если после этого вновь срабатывает
> a[i]>a[i-1], то идет добавление в d и до конца списка. В чем-то
> напоминает условия для входа и выхода из биржевой сделки
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> В моем исполнении код возвращает исходный список, а должно получиться
> [2,1,2,3]

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3,4,5,3]
d=[]

for i in range(1,len(a)):
    if a[i]>a[i-1]:
        b=a[i]
    elif a[i]>a[i-1]:
        continue
    if a[i]<a[i-1]:
       b=a[i]

    d.append(b)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
    d = []
    perekl = 0
    
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[i] > a[i-1] and perekl == 2 or a[i] > a[i-1] and perekl == 0:
            perekl = 3
            d.append(a[i])
            continue
        if a[i] < a[i-1] and perekl == 3 or a[i] < a[i-1] and perekl == 0:
            perekl = 2
            d.append(a[i])
    
    
    print(d)
```

Выше код, если мы ждем, что первое либо a[i] > a[i-1] либо a[i] < a[i-1] поэтому ставим   perekl == 0, так как не знаем что сработает первым.
Если же нужно чтобы первое срабатывание было именно a[i] > a[i-1],
то смотрите код ниже.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
d = []
perekl = 2

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] > a[i-1] and perekl == 2:
        perekl = 3
        d.append(a[i])
        continue
    if a[i] < a[i-1] and perekl == 3:
        perekl = 2
        d.append(a[i])


print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не разбирая логики, добавьте некий флаг, который будет обозначать в какой именно стадии вы находитесь и добавьте проверку на равенство членов

```py
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3,4,5,3]
d=[]
up = True # флаг
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    if a[i]>a[i-1] and up: 
        b=a[i]
        up = False # после первого попадания, опускаете флаг
    elif a[i]>a[i-1]:
        continue
    elif a[i] == a[i-1]:
        continue
    if a[i]<a[i-1]:
       b=a[i]
       up = True # при срабатывания противоположного условия, снова поднимаете флаг и тд
    d.append(b)

print(d)
```